# Count the number of lists containing specific element in a nested list with mapreduce

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, mapreduce, rdd

I have a list of lists containing strings and I want to count in how many of those lists each element appears:

```
list_of_lists = [["dog", "cow"], ["dragon", "ox", "cow"], ["fox", "cow", "dog"]]
```

So, `cow` appears in 3 lists, `dog` appears in 2 etc.

For such a small dataset, I would normally do:

```
from collections import Counter
from itertools import chain
count = Counter(chain.from_iterable(set(x) for x in list_of_lists))
```

and thus:

```
print(count["dog"])
2
```

However, I want to do that for a large dataset using PySpark and MapReduce so that for each element in the list of lists, I would have the above counter value:

```
    [("dog", 2),
    ("cow", 3),
    ("dragon", 1),
    ("ox", 1),
    ("fox", 1)]
```

etc.

I am trying things like:

```
list_of_lists = sc.parallelize(list_of_lists)
list_occurencies = list_of_lists.map(lambda x: x, count[x])
```

with no effect

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `flatMap` to flatten the nested arrays then `reduceByKey` to get the count of each word in the list:

```
list_of_lists = sc.parallelize(list_of_lists)

list_of_lists = list_of_lists.flatMap(lambda x: set(x))\
    .map(lambda x: (x, 1))\
    .reduceByKey(lambda a, b: a + b)

print(list_of_lists.collect())
# [('fox', 1), ('dragon', 1), ('ox', 1), ('dog', 2), ('cow', 3)]
```